# What would be a more pythonic way of constructing this command and running it

Tags: python, python-3.x, qpython3

```
os.system(sys.executable+" "+sys.prefix+"/bin/"+arg)
```

This is part of the pip console app that comes with qpython for android

Comment: `os.system("".join([sys.executable, " ", sys.prefix, "/bin/", arg]))` ?

Answer (score 3):

A better way might be to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
from subprocess import run
from os.path import join
from sys import executable, prefix
run([executable, join(prefix, 'bin', arg)])
```

The interface is much cleaner and more robust. It also offers much more control over how the process is called.

Notice that you can use a list for the arguments instead of artificially concatenating them. This makes life much easier if the path contains a space.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is more pythonic but still needs something.

```
def modcmd(arg):
    exe = sys.executable + ' '
    prefix = sys.prefix + '/bin/'
    cmd = exe + prefix + arg
    os.system('clear')
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: This function is ran in a REPL. I like to clear the screen before displaying the output of the next command.

Comment: I don't think this is more Pythonic: you are still using the same function and constructing paths using string concatenation.

Comment: The documentation for `os.system` itself recommends using the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: It's more pythonic because it's prettyer.

Comment: @RickyWilson. It is not prettier. It obfuscates the code in subtle ways, e.g. `exe` has a space in it. And more Pythonic is not synonymous with prettier.

Comment: I will replace os.system with subprocess as recommended. I felt dirty using it anyway.